# Integrating with respect to Poisson distribution

Tags: integration, poisson-distribution, levy-processes

If $F$ is a distribution with mean $\mu_1$ and with $F(0)=0$, how do I integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty y\,F(\mathrm dy)\;$? This question is based on the compounded Poisson process, $S(t)=\sum^{N(t)}_{k=1}Y_k$, where $N(t)\sim\mathrm{Po}(\lambda_1)$and $Y_k$ are i.i.d. non-negative random variables with distribution $F(\cdot)$.

Comment: This is an ordinary lebesgue integral and the actual computation depends on the distribution. Does $F$ have a density $f$? If so you can use that $$\int _0^\infty g(y)F(dy)=\int_0^\infty g(y) f(y)dy.$$

Comment: @Vincent.W. you are right its just a question of notation